How does the force acting on the oppositely charged particles get decreased by the polarization of the material when submerged
Explain the answer by explaining how the polarization occurs and if the polarisation occurs how does that polarisation make the force acting on the oppositely charged particles to decrease when submerged in a medium?
Polarisation occurs around the charges
I came to know that if dielectric is placed between the two oppositely charged charges then the forces on them increases but if they are submerged in a medium of dielectric constant k then equation tell us that force is decreased but i wanted to know this explanation thereotically?
I am confused about this concept. please help me by answering this question ?

Decreased is the correct answer. Your argument for why it increases is incomprehensible.

I am asking to explain how it decreases in terms of polarization

The main paragraph of your question is a confusing run-on sentence that makes it hard to understand your argument why the force should increase.  Is your question the same as "How do we conclude that polarized dielectric in electric field reduces overall field?" or "Shouldn't the electric dipoles (and thus dielectrics) increase the net electric field?".  Does this answer help: "Why does electric force depend on the medium?"?

The dielectric contains many tiny pairs of positive and negative charges each bound together like springs. When there is no electric field applied, the positive and negative charges exactly coincide and there is no polarization. In other words, the "extension" of the springs is zero.
In the presence of an applied electric field, the positive charges of the dielectric move in the direction of the applied electric field while the negative charges move in the opposite direction. This results in an overall dipole moment (i.e. polarization) in the same direction as the applied field. These (newly-created) dipoles then have their own electric field which goes from the positive ends of the dipole to the negative ends. This is opposite to the applied electric field so it decreases the overall electric field strength. The factor by which it is decreased is the relative permittivity, $\varepsilon_r \ge 1$.
Therefore, a point charge $q$ placed in a large homogeneous linear dielectric has a weaker electric field
$$\frac{q}{4\pi\varepsilon_r\varepsilon_0 r^2}\hat{\mathbf{r}}.$$
A weaker electric field results in a smaller force experienced by another charge.

I came to know that if dielectric is placed between the two oppositely charged charges then the forces on them increases but if they are submerged in a medium of dielectric constant k then equation tell us that force is decreased but i wanted to know this explanation thereotically

Polarisation of the medium gives rise to a 'halo' of negative charge (negative ends of dipoles) around any positively charged body, A, surrounded by the medium. This reduces the apparent charge on the body, as judged from the reduced force experienced by another charged body, B, in the medium. B's apparent charge will be reduced by the same mechanism.
